# UITextFieldDelegate not delegating on prod environment swift 4.2

Tags: swift4.2

I have recently updated my project to swift 4.2, and tested full app, every thing is working fine on debug environment, but once i try run it on release environment i do not get delegate from UITextField, it is a weird behaviour, did anyone faced the similar situation.

Comment: whoever has downvoted, please add the reason or solution.

Comment: my project is multi target project, and it is creating issue only for Production Target and release build configuration.

Comment: resolved by setting Compilation Mode to Incremental

Comment: Has the issue been resolved by setting compilation Mode to Incremental?

Comment: it is resolved while running app locally, but when we release by creating Archive issue is there :(